# is there a CSS attribute that makes a too big object fit the screen?

Tags: html, css

For instance, I have a `div`, that is `10 000px by 10 000px` and I want it to fit on any screen, like its height and width would be `10 000px` and not just `100%`, but the scroll bar wouldn't be there and I **wouldn't** be able to scroll until the `div`'s bottom and right side

Comment: There is a non-standard CSS `zoom` property that might be of interest if I have understood your question correctly

Comment: scale transformation but you will need JS to get scale factor (CSS can do it in the future)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the div in another div. Give the wrapping div overflow: hidden; and max-height of maybe 100vh if that's what your going for.

```
.out {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
}

.in {
    width: 10000px;
    height: 10000px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/p2c76y1s/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try playing with `position: absolute` and `overflow: visible`

```
.div-class {
    height: 10000px;
    width: 10000px;
    position: absolute; //disconnect the element from ather components
    //top, bottom, left, right used to position the absolute element
    top: X;
    bottom: X;
    left: X;
    right: X;
    overflow: visible; //disable the scroll
}
```